# numpy add dimension to array

Tags: python, numpy

I get a python object, which has dimension (10, ). I want to change it to array with shape (10, 1).

For example：

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 3))
x = x[:, 0]
x.shape
# which is (10, )

y = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1))
y.shape
# which is (10, 1)

z = x + y
z.shape
# which is (10, 10)
```

How can I accomplish this?
plus, why does the z variable above get a (10, 10) shape?

Comment: So how far have you gotten in your `numpy` introduction?  Changing array `shape` should be in chapter one, two at the latest.  Adding two arrays, and broadcasting rules, should be part of the intro as well.  https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need use `numpy.array`

`x = x[:, 0]` is equal to  `x = np.array(x[:, 0])`

---

you can indicate that **you want an additional** dimension and you do not give up explicitly indexing the first column:

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 3))
x = x[:, 0, None]
x.shape
#(10, 1)
```

Or you can use it when you sum

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 3))
y = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1))
#x[:, 0, None] + y
x = x[:, 0]
x[:, None] + y
```

We can also indicate that we want everything before the second column, this syntax is shorter but perhaps it is more readable `0` than `:1`

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 3))
x = x[:, :1]
x.shape
#(10, 1)
```

we could also use additional methods.

#### [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 3))
x = np.expand_dims(x[:, 0], 1)
x.shape
#(10, 1)
```

#### [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 3))
x = x[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
x.shape
#(10, 1)
```

Here the `-1` allows this to work with another number of rows different from 10

Answer (score 1):

To change the shape you could add this piece of code-

```py
np.reshape(x, (10,1))
```

Which would resize the `x` to `(10,1)` and return it

Comment: really specifying 10 could be an error, here we can use `-1`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 3))
x = np.array(x[:, 0])
x = np.reshape(x, (10, 1))  # this line added
x.shape
# which is (10, )

y = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1))
y.shape
# which is (10, 1)

z = x + y
z.shape
# which is (10, 10)
```

Comment: really specifying 10 could be an error, here we can use `-1`